# Setting border color of UISearchBar in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, tintcolor

My xib contains a UITableView and a UISearchDisplayController.  I'm setting colors and having a bit of trouble with the search bar.

I'm setting its color like this:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
```

The section headers in the table are set to the same color.

There are three problems:

- there's a noticeable (probably 1 px) white stripe between the top of
  the search bar and the nav bar
- there's a similar black stripe between
  the bottom of the search bar and the first section header in the
  table
- even though the search bar and section headers are the same
  color, the search bar appears slightly darker

Is there a technique for making this look right/better?

Edit: here's what it looks like:

[image: screencapture]

Comment: can you show the image of the screen?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have subclassed UISearchBar and used the UIAppearance proxy on it, however, I get a black line at the top of mine...

Comment: Sorry, no I never did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: I tried this, substituting my color from above, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *sub in self.tableView.tableHeaderView.subviews) {
    if ([sub isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        sub.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1;
searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

By the way you have to do both. Setting just borderColor property didn't work for me!